# Traffic Light Onload Function

Tags: javascript, html, css

So for my coursework I have to make a traffic light that runs without any input so automatically, which brought me to the onload function in javascript which runs scripts when a page is loaded. I was wondering how to correctly implement this in my current code. I would also like the traffic light to cycle through colours with a time delay, which can be done through set interval. I was struggling to correctly add  both of these functions to let it work. I reused the css code from before.
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Traffic Light Script </title> <!-- Name for the above tab -->
<link href="TrafficCascade.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body onload="functionary()">   
<h1> Traffic Light </h1><!-- -->
<table> <!-- -->
<tr>
<td>
<div id="redL"></div>
<div id="yellowL"></div>
<div id="greenL"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="gogled.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#redL{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin: 1px auto;
background-color: #7A0000;
border-radius: 50px;
border: solid 1px black;
padding: 1px;
}
#yellowL{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin: 1px auto;
background-color: #7A5C00;
border-radius: 50px; 
border: solid 1px black;
padding: 1px;
}
#greenL{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin: 1px auto;
background-color: #008000;
border-radius: 50px;
border: solid 1px black;
padding: 1px;
}
table{         /* Doesn't need dashes */
height: 180px;
width: 80px;
background-color: #000000;
border: 1px #000000;
text-align: center; 
margin-left: 50%; /* makes margin right 50% */
padding: 1px;
}
h1{
text-align: center;
padding: 1px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var time = 5;
function functionary() {
var red = document.getElementById('redL')
var yellow = document.getElementById('yellowL')
var green = document.getElementById('greenL')
var Colours = ["#FF0000","#FFB300","#05FF0D","#7A0000","#7A5C00","#008000"];
setInterval(function(){
if(time == 5){
    red.style.background = Colours[0]; // May need spacebar between index    number
    yellow.style.background = Colours[4];
    green.style.background = Colours[5];
    time = 1;
} 
else if(time == 2 || time == 4){
    red.style.background = Colours[3];
    yellow.style.background = Colours[1];
    green.style.background = Colours[5];
}
else if(time == 3){
    red.style.background = Colours[3];
    yellow.style.background = Colours[4];
    green.style.background = Colours[2];
}, 3000)
};
```

Comment: If this is your coursework you should *at the very least* show us what you have tried. At the moment this is just a **give me the code** request. Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561465/traffic-light-coursework-a452

Comment: Umm dude its right there? Unless i formatted the code incorrectly.

Comment: I was just looking for improvements to my code and perhaps simple explanations to the functions i requested help in and how to use them correctly/ the syntax.

Comment: Lol even in my previous one i showed my code. Is this a troll?

Comment: </head>
<body onload="functionary()">   
<h1> Traffic Light </h1><!-- -->

Comment: Can you see the code mate? I can see it?

Comment: Oh wait soz dude i forgot to add it lol. Yhh i see the problem let me edit it.

Comment: ...and that's it. What errors did you get.?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j0sn4ta2/

Comment: No i meant when you saw nothing. I copied my previous code not the one for the onload function with setinterval. It should be implemented now.

Comment: Are you incrementing the time variable somewhere?

Comment: Added it yhh  3000ms at the bottom for the whole function which is under the set interval.

Comment: I see your `setInterval`, but I don't see where you are incrementing `time`. You set it to 5. Then if it is 5, you set it to 1. Then nothing. Also, the `setInterval` is not closed properly in your above code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j0sn4ta2/5/ I updated the code on there to represent what i have on Notepad ++ I ran the code and it works fine but for some reason it doesnt work on JSfiddle. Btw im very new to coding and the site.

Comment: Do you know how to check your console for errors?

Comment: Do you mean on a browser through inspect element and the error checker there?

Comment: Yep! Check that last fiddle you posted. You'll see some errors. I'd start there. If you see it says the function you are calling is undefined.

Comment: The setinverval is set to 3000ms on the 2nd to last line in js. Time is a just a random var that i made that holds a order of values. The set interval should be adding 1 to this value each time hence the reset back to 1 to go to 2 then 3 for the if / else statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved your `setInterval` outside of your function. The `body` element calls the function `onload`. Every 3000ms `setInterval` calls the function.

**JS:**

```
var time = 5;

function functionary() {
  var red = document.getElementById('redL')
  var yellow = document.getElementById('yellowL')
  var green = document.getElementById('greenL')
  var Colours = ["#FF0000", "#FFB300", "#05FF0D", "#7A0000", "#7A5C00", "#008000"];
  if (time == 5) {
    red.style.background = Colours[0]; // May need spacebar between index number
    yellow.style.background = Colours[4];
    green.style.background = Colours[5];
    time = 1;
  } else if (time == 2 || time == 4) {
    red.style.background = Colours[3];
    yellow.style.background = Colours[1];
    green.style.background = Colours[5];
  } else if (time == 3) {
    red.style.background = Colours[3];
    yellow.style.background = Colours[4];
    green.style.background = Colours[2];
  }
  time += 1;
};
setInterval(function() {
  functionary();
}, 3000);
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/adv7exap/

Comment: Thanks this makes much more sense repeating the whole function from outside the script.

Comment: No problem! You can also achieve this by using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` by placing a `setTimeout` inside the function that calls the function again.

Comment: Well dude I can't say thanks enoguh been a bit under the weather for a while cause i was struggling and my friends wouldn't help me, but your helps been great dude. Well appreciated.